# manifolds vs orbifolds vs orientifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, mathematical-physics

Could someone explain the difference between manifolds, orbifolds, and orientifolds? I would like to see some basic examples.

Thanks.

Comment: This is too vague.  The relevant wikipedia pages contain definitions and examples...why not start there?  Note that orientifolds are a rather specialized notion...if you aren't clear on manifolds and orbifolds, I suggest starting there.